# Jquery .remove event only on parent not child

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$(".alert").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(300, function(){            
        $(this).remove();            
    });
});
</script>

<div class="alert alert-error">                
    <h4>title</h4>
    <textarea class="pull-right">text...</textarea>
</div>
```

So the above code works perfectly except that I need to make it so that a user can select the text inside the textarea. At this moment logically when they click the textarea, as its contained by .alert, it instantly gets removed with the div.

I can't remove the textarea from the div as I need it both contained by the div, and removed when other parts of the div are clicked.

So how can I specifically exclude the textarea from the click event of its containing div while still allowing the click event from the containing div to remove the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by preventing the `click` event from propagating (bubbling) from the `textarea` to the `div`:

```
$(".alert textarea").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropgation();
});
```

Example:

```js
$(".alert").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(300, function(){            
        $(this).remove();            
    });
});
$(".alert textarea").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-error">                
    <h4>title</h4>
    <textarea class="pull-right">text...</textarea>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternately, in your existing handler, check to see if the event passed through the `textarea`:

```
$(".alert").click(function(e){
  if (!$(e.target).closest("textarea").length) {
    $(this).fadeOut(300, function(){            
        $(this).remove();            
    });
  }
});
```

Example:

```js
$(".alert").click(function(e){
  if (!$(e.target).closest("textarea").length) {
    $(this).fadeOut(300, function(){            
        $(this).remove();            
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-error">                
    <h4>title</h4>
    <textarea class="pull-right">text...</textarea>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that that second one relies on the fact that your `.alert` element can never be *inside* another `textarea`, because of the nature of the elements. It won't work in the general case. This would, but it's a pain:

```
$(".alert").click(function(e){
  var $t = $(e.target);
  if (!$t.is("textarea") && !$t.parentsUntil(this, "textarea").length) {
    $(this).fadeOut(300, function(){            
        $(this).remove();            
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the not selector to do this :

```
<script>
$(".alert *:not(textarea)").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(300, function(){            
        $(this).parent().remove();            
    });
});
</script>

<div class="alert alert-error">                
    <h4>title</h4>
    <textarea class="pull-right">text...</textarea>
</div>
```

see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zLq6dztu/

Comment: This is very handy indeed. I didn't realize there was a not selector.

Comment: @Bruce & Gatsbill: That won't work for clicks on the `.alert` element *itself* rather than on one of its descendants (the alert doesn't close): https://jsfiddle.net/t6faLep4/ It also won't work if the `textarea` is inside a descendant of `.alert` rather than directly contained in the `.alert` (the alert closes when you click the `textarea`): https://jsfiddle.net/t6faLep4/2/